Unbound expression when using constraint programming (CPLEX)
I am coding the model using CP based on the paper "A Constraint Programming Approach to Electric Vehicle Routing with Time Windows" by Kyle.E.C.Booth
using CP;

int NoDepot = ...;
int NoCharge = ...;
int NoCustomer = ...;
int NoVehicle = ...;

range depot = 1 .. NoDepot;
range dummydepot = NoDepot+1 .. NoDepot*2;
range charge = NoDepot*2+1 .. NoDepot*2+NoCharge;
range customer = NoDepot*2+NoCharge+1 .. NoDepot*2+NoCharge+NoCustomer;
range allnode = 1..NoDepot*2+NoCharge+NoCustomer;
range vehicle = 1..NoVehicle;

int start[allnode] = ...;
int end[allnode] = ...;

int demand[customer] = ...;
int servicetime[customer] = ...;
int batterycapa[vehicle] = ...;
int loadcapa[vehicle] = ...;

int consumerate = 1;
int rechargerate = 1;

int alpha = 1;
int beta = 1;

int distancematrix[0..NoDepot*2+NoCharge+NoCustomer][0..NoDepot*2+NoCharge+NoCustomer] = ...; 
int timematrix[0..NoDepot*2+NoCharge+NoCustomer][0..NoDepot*2+NoCharge+NoCustomer] = ...;

tuple triplet { int id1; int id2; int value; };
{triplet} Mdist = {<id1,id2,distancematrix[id1][id2]> | id1,id2 in allnode};
{triplet} Mtime = {<id1,id2,timematrix[id1][id2]> | id1,id2 in allnode};

dvar interval visit[c in customer] in start[c]..end[c] size servicetime[c];
dvar interval vehvisit_dist[a in allnode][v in vehicle] optional size 0;
dvar interval vehvisit_time[a in allnode][v in vehicle] optional;

dvar sequence route_dist[v in vehicle] in all (a in allnode)vehvisit_dist[a][v] types all(a in allnode) a;
dvar sequence route_time[v in vehicle] in all (a in allnode)vehvisit_time[a][v] types all(a in allnode) a;

dvar interval vehicle_dist[v in vehicle] optional;


cumulFunction carry_load[v in vehicle] = stepAtStart(vehvisit_time[1][v],loadcapa[v]) 
                - sum(c in customer)stepAtStart(vehvisit_time[c][v],demand[c]);

cumulFunction battery_load[v in vehicle] = stepAtStart(vehvisit_time[1][v],batterycapa[v]) 
    - sum(b in allnode)stepAtEnd(vehvisit_time[b][v],distancematrix[typeOfPrev(route_time[v], vehvisit_time[b][v],0,0)][b]) + sum(f in charge)stepAtStart(vehvisit_time[f][v],0,batterycapa[v]);


subject to
{
    
    ct1:
    forall(c in customer)
        alternative(visit[c],all(v in vehicle)vehvisit_time[c][v]);
    
    ct2:
    forall(v in vehicle)
        noOverlap(route_dist[v],Mdist,true);
    
    ct3:
    forall(v in vehicle)
        noOverlap(route_time[v],Mtime,true);
    
    ct4:
    forall(v in vehicle)
        sameSequence(route_dist[v], route_time[v]);
    
    ct5:
    forall(v in vehicle)
        presenceOf(vehvisit_time[1][v]);
        
    ct6:
    forall(v in vehicle)
        presenceOf(vehvisit_time[2][v]);

    ct7:
    forall(v in vehicle)
    {
        first(route_time[v],vehvisit_time[1][v]);
        last(route_time[v],vehvisit_time[2][v]);        
    }   
    
    ct8:
    forall(v in vehicle)
        span(vehicle_dist[v], all(a in allnode)vehvisit_time[a][v]);

    ct9:
    forall(v in vehicle)
        alwaysIn(carry_load[v],start[1], end[1], 0, loadcapa[v]);
    
    ct10:
    forall(v in vehicle)
        alwaysIn(battery_load[v],start[1], end[1], 0, batterycapa[v]);
    
    ct11:
    forall(v in vehicle, f in charge)
        alwaysIn(battery_load[v],vehvisit_time[f][v],batterycapa[v],batterycapa[v]);
}


///////////// .dat file
SheetConnection file("final.xlsx");

NoDepot from SheetRead(file, "NoDepot");
NoCharge from SheetRead(file, "NoCharge");
NoCustomer from SheetRead(file, "NoCustomer");
NoVehicle from SheetRead(file, "NoVehicle");
start from SheetRead(file, "start");
end from SheetRead(file, "end");
demand from SheetRead(file, "demand");
servicetime from SheetRead(file, "servicetime");
batterycapa from SheetRead(file, "batterycapa");
loadcapa from SheetRead(file, "loadcapa");
distancematrix from SheetRead(file, "dist");
timematrix from SheetRead(file, "time");




Link data in format excel:: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ou-AO-CmWz80dynkEivm432rjBPfCSWY/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=110647671445738653790&rtpof=true&sd=true
I have an error:
Unbound expression: distancematrix[typeOfPrev(route_time[v1],vehvisit_time[b][v1],0,0)][b] in side stepAtStart function.
I have try many times but it not work, please help me, thanks
update 1:
I have read document of ibm about function stepAtStart([interval variable], int hmin, int hmax)

hmax & hmin are pre-defined, like distance matrix. But I still get error

update 2:
I found that function 'typeOfPrev' can not be inside function 'stepAtEnd'

why not sharing .dat so that other users can try ?

@AlexFleischer I have added data and dat file. Thanks

The height in StepAtEnd can be an integer or two integer bounds, but not an expression involving constrained variables.

I understand that, but is there any way involving constrainted variable ? because my problem is the battery remain will reduce based on the distance between two point . So that I have to use typeOfPrev inside stepAtStart @Olivier Lhomme

What I would use is an alternative with all trips that go to C : A->C and B->C , you write a stepAtStart for all those interval. Only the interval that is present will contribute to the cumul and the value of the stepAtStart is the distance.
At https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/tspcpo.mod I shared a small example of distance matrix and scheduling
using CP; 
int     n       = ...;
range   Cities  = 1..n;

int realCity[i in 1..n+1]=(i<=n)?i:1;



// Edges -- sparse set
tuple       edge        {int i; int j;}
setof(edge) Edges       = {<i,j> | ordered i,j in 1..n};
setof(edge) Edges2       = {<i,j> | i,j in 1..n+1};  // node n+1 is node 1

int         dist[Edges] = ...;
int         dist2[<i,j> in Edges2]=(realCity[i]==realCity[j])?0:
((realCity[i]<realCity[j])?dist[<realCity[i],realCity[j]>]:dist[<realCity[j],realCity[i]>]);


dvar interval itvs[1..n+1] size 1;


dvar sequence seq in all(i in 1..n+1) itvs[i]; 

execute
{

cp.param.TimeLimit=60;
var f = cp.factory;
  cp.setSearchPhases(f.searchPhase(seq));
}

tuple triplet { int c1; int c2; int d; };
{triplet} Dist = { 
    <i-1,j-1,dist2[<i ,j >]>
           |  i,j in 1..n+1};
           
           
minimize endOf(itvs[n+1]) - (n+1);           
subject to
{
    startOf(itvs[1])==0; // break sym
    noOverlap(seq,Dist,true);   // nooverlap with a distance matrix
    last(seq, itvs[n+1]); // last node
}

